# Randomising element selection for Cypress tests

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

Currently testing a local movie booking website, where I have to enter a certain number of tickets for a selected movie. Screenshot of the attached screen here -

[image]

Repository for reproducing the problem - https://github.com/zac11/iCinema

1. Clone the repo.
2. Go inside the `client` directory and do `npm i`
3. Run `npm start` from root directory.
4. Webapp will open at `localhost:3000`

I want to be able to enter the movie tickets for the selected movies in a random manner in such a way that it selects a random category of ticket our of the four and enters a ticket number say 2

Right now I can fill the ticket category by hard coding the locator in this way -

```
  cy.get('div.tickets-info > div:nth-child(1) > span > b').type(3,{force:true});
```

which enters ticket count for `Junior Ticket` category. I want to be able to enter a ticket in any one of the four categories randomly without having to hardcode the category locator.

PS - The repository contains the cypress tests also which can be run using `npm run test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could randomise the category based on the following:

```js
const picked = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); // this gives you a random value from 0 - 3;

// using template string literals - we can add that into picked
cy.get(`div.tickets-info > div:nth-child(`${picked}`) > span > b`).type(3, {force: true})
```

from picked - you can have an array of elements which related to the categories:

```js
const categories = ["Junior", "student", "normal", "senior"]
```

You could also have the values of the tickets in `categories` as objects and use that for calculating the total.

```js
const categories = [{
  type: "junior", 
  value: 5
}, {
  type: "student",
  value: 3
}, {
  type: "normal"
  value: 10
}, {
  type: "senior",
  value: 3
}]
```

and you could say, use the picked value to calculate the total amount

```js
const value = categories[picked].value * random_amount;
cy.get(".sum-field label:nth-child(1)").should("contain", value) // total
```

Comment: `const picked = Math.floor(Math.random*3);` returns a `NaN`. I fixed it by using                ` const picked = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

Comment: sorry that was a typo - did this too late at night

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same with our app so I came up with a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) to achieve this easily. Here's the code I came up with in `cypress/support/commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('any', { prevSubject: 'element' }, (subject, size = 1) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject).then(elementList => {

    // this line enables me to use this command with either cy.get() or cy.wrap()
    elementList = (elementList.jquery) ? elementList.get() : elementList;

    elementList = Cypress._.sampleSize(elementList, size);
    elementList = (elementList.length > 1) ? elementList : elementList[0];

    return cy.wrap(elementList);
  });
});
```

I can also use custom logging with [Cypress.log()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Command-Logging) in your custom commands. I removed it from the above code for clarity.

You then use it in your tests just like any other cy commands:

```
cy.get('div.tickets-info > div > span > b').any().type(3,{force:true});
```

or if you need more than one:

```
cy.get('div.tickets-info > div > span > b').any(2).each(element => {
    cy.wrap(element).type(2, { force: true });
});
```